# Load an image into an html within a Webview

Tags: javascript, html, react-native, webview

I'm loading my html inside the `webView`

```
<WebViewBridge
    ref="webviewbridge"
    onBridgeMessage={this.onBridgeMessage}
    javaScriptEnabled={true}
    injectedJavaScript={injectScript}
    source={require('./Canvas.html')} ==> Here
/>
```

And inside the `/Canvas.html/` file i have.

`<img id="deleteImg" src="../../../../assets/images/close-red.png" width="20" height="20" style="display:none; position: absolute; z-index: 1000">`

This path `../../../../assets/images/close-red.png` works perfect if used in react-native code. But when I post it in the html, it shows up with a blue question mark

[image]

Comment: Copy the image to ios/android native folders. That way you can reach the file with device path

Comment: Have you found a solution to this problem?